# How can I set mapView's userLocation to a MKUserLocation that I created?

Tags: ios5, mkmapview, userlocation

Im trying to do some coding about improving the iPhone positioning accuracy.
I got all needed info(e.g. latitude, longitude, deviceMotion, Gyro..) from my iPhone hardware and need to display the more accurate calculation result on the mapView.
But just then I found that the userLocation property of the mapView is readonly, so it probably means it cannot be changed even use the setCoordinate method, so sad =[
Is there any solution that can deal with it or there has another way to display that position on my map view?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to create CLLocationCoordinate2D with CLLocationCoordinate2DMake and set there latitude a longitude.
Then create your position as new MKAnotation (for example yourPositionAnotation) and set there your position from CLLocationCoordinate2D as a coordinate. Then do just something like this:

```
// create coordinate
CLLocationCoordinate2D yourPos = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat, lon);
// create MKAnnotation
MKAnnotationView *yourAnnotation = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] init];

yourAnnotation.coordinate = yourPos;

// remove all old annotations
[self.myMapView removeAnnotations:self.myMapView.annotations]
// add your annotation
[self.myMapView addAnnotation:yourAnnotation];
```

Don't forget release annotation in the end.

Comment: Your idea is great!I think using Core Graphic to draw a point on the map is also works but carries much more coding than yours, thanks a million!